# How to generate password protected excel report using JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, password-protection

I am trying to generate a simple password protected excel report.

Java code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JExcelApiExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JExcelApiExporterParameter;

public class Report {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JasperReport jasperReport;
            JasperPrint jasperPrint;

            Connection connection = establishConnection();
            HashMap jasperParameter = new HashMap();

            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("D:\\Jasper\\report1.jrxml");
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, jasperParameter, connection);

            JExcelApiExporter exporter = new JExcelApiExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "D:\\Jasper\\simple_report.xls");
            exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.PASSWORD, "sam");

            exporter.exportReport();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection establishConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String mySQL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mySQL, "root", "Infy123+");
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

report1.jrxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports     http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy"     pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20"     topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ac32c69e-bb80-4dc5-9139-f9b085ffa739">
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM test.item]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ITEM_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ITEM_DESCIPTION" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ITEM_AMOUNT" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="36" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="41" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="13" y="11" width="100" height="20"     uuid="97ab8c4f-ec9e-47a1-807e-37e2adbf9d36"/>
                <text><![CDATA[ITEM NAME]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="43" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="13" y="11" width="100" height="20"     uuid="0fe760df-5c76-499f-8f79-3308680e9a37"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ITEM_NAME}]]>        </textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The file is getting generated but is not password protected.

I am using *JasperReports-5.5.0* and *iReport 5.5.0*.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the editing of the Excel report using the inbuilt POI api provided in the JasperReport. However, excel can still be opened.

The password protected is applicable only for the Excel editing option.

I would also be interested to know if there's a way to password protect excel document itself.. Could not find anything in Apache POI.